# Validation Rule Using IsPickVal Question

Tags: formula, validation

I am trying to put a validation rule together that fires if certain values on a picklist field are populated and then requires the user to populate a contact field called "DV Perpetrator / Opposing Party". The following syntax is firing, but once I populate the "DV Perpetrator / Opposing Party" field, it still will not allow me to save. How do I add the "DV Perpetrator / Opposing Party" criteria?

CASE(Presenting_Need_of_Case__c,
"Legal - Divorce",               1,
"Counseling - Domestic Violence",1,
"Immigration - UVisa/VAWA",      1,
"Shelter - Domestic Violence",   1,
"Legal - Divorce",               1,
"Legal - Order of Protection",   1,
0) = 1

Comment: So I've updated my rule to the following:

CASE(Presenting_Need_of_Case__c,
"Legal - Divorce",               1,
"Counseling - Domestic Violence",1,
"Immigration - UVisa/VAWA",      1,
"Shelter - Domestic Violence",   1,
"Legal - Divorce",               1,
"Legal - Order of Protection",   1,
0) = 1

but i've realized I'm missing some criteria, what do I add to say if any one of those picklist values are populated then you are required to populate the contact field "DV Perpetrator / Opposing Party" ?

Answer (score 3):

You do not need an IF just use the OR conditions.

```
OR(
ISPICKVAL(Presenting_Need_of_Case__c,"Legal - Divorce"),
ISPICKVAL(Presenting_Need_of_Case__c,"Counseling - Domestic Violence"),
ISPICKVAL(Presenting_Need_of_Case__c,"Immigration - UVisa/VAWA"),
ISPICKVAL(Presenting_Need_of_Case__c,"Shelter - Domestic Violence"),
ISPICKVAL(Presenting_Need_of_Case__c,"Legal - Divorce"),
ISPICKVAL(Presenting_Need_of_Case__c,"Legal - Order of Protection")
)
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation about what was actually wrong?

Answer (score 2):

While your function works, it's actually *very* inefficient. You should be able do something like this:

```
CASE(Presenting_Need_of_Case__c,
"Legal - Divorce",               1,
"Counseling - Domestic Violence",1,
"Immigration - UVisa/VAWA",      1,
"Shelter - Domestic Violence",   1,
"Legal - Divorce",               1,
"Legal - Order of Protection",   1,
0) = 1
```

This will reduce your compiled formula size by several kilobytes of code.

Comment: Couldn't you replace all the `1`s with `TRUE` and the `0` with `FALSE` and then remove the equality comparison altogether?

Comment: @AdrianLarson You can't actually; you'll get an "invalid argument for case" error. I devised this workaround as a hack to work around that.

Comment: Gotcha. I guess that makes sense.

Comment: So I've updated my rule to the following:

CASE(Presenting_Need_of_Case__c,
"Legal - Divorce",               1,
"Counseling - Domestic Violence",1,
"Immigration - UVisa/VAWA",      1,
"Shelter - Domestic Violence",   1,
"Legal - Divorce",               1,
"Legal - Order of Protection",   1,
0) = 1

but i've realized I'm missing some criteria, what do I add to say if any one of those picklist values are populated then you are required to populate the contact field "DV Perpetrator / Opposing Party" ?

Comment: @KateHolden `(previous.formula) && ISBLANK(...)`, or `AND( (previous.formula), ISBLANK(...))`

Answer (score 1):

Couple things.

- You're actually missing commas.

  - `OR` syntax is `OR(condition1, condition2, ...)`
  - The "missing parenthesis" is the closing paren above, because without commas only one clause is required.
- `IF` syntax is: `IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)`

So it should actually look like:

```
IF(OR(
    ISPICKVAL(...),
    ISPICKVAL(...),
), "value if true", "value if false")
```

Or if you just want the `Boolean` value of `logical_test`, remove the `IF` function altogether.

Comment: A man got to make his comeback after being away for a while :(, let loose of these smaller goose Adrian :)

Comment: Hey I voted for you! +1 all around. :) Welcome back. @rao